# Backbone Router… how to deal with url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, url-routing, backbone-routing

I have an application which main files look like these (1), (2), (3).

The Backbone.Router works fine in this case (because it triggers `#page`):

```
http://localhost/index.php#page
```

How should I configure it if the url is the following (in order to trigger `/some#page`):

```
http://localhost/index.php/some#page
```

P.S:
the backend of this web app is using Synfony2

---

(1)

```
// index.php
<script data-main='mainApp.js' src='require.js'>
```

---

(2)

```
// mainApp.js
define([
  'js/router'
], function(Router) {
    "use strict";
    var initialize = function ()
    {
            Router.initialize();
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

---

(3)

```
// router.js
define([
    'myView'
], function(MyView){
    console.log(MyView)
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
           'page' : 'view'
        },

        view: function () {
          //some code
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
routes: { 
   '/some:page': 'view',
}
```